# e-mail and Android mail account settings from code

Tags: android, ios, email, settings, device-manager

Is there a way to **create**/change an **email account from source** at android an ios? We would like to provide our customer a way for adding their mail accounts to android and ios devices within in an app.

I've already taken a look at the **Android** Account Manager but I'm still not sure if I can add System-Mail Accounts with it(example..?) :(

[API: Android Account Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

For **IOS** up to now i haven't found anything :(

Answer (score 1):

For iOs you will have to create a configuration profile using the [iPhone Configuration Utility for Mac OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL851) or [for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL926). Basically those are XML/Plist-Files - only some content is obfuscated (like passwords). But if you don't include passwords you can modify this xml content in your app then you should be able to create a local NSURL and call UIApplication's openURL. if that doesn't work you'll have to deploy your configurations from a webserver - there is a [guide](http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html) for that. In that case you have to create a http-NSURL and pass that to openURL.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have anyone an idea if there is something similar for android?